# How to Sort data from calculating two different arrays data. using Collection

Tags: java, android, arrays, collections, android-recyclerview

I want to sort data by calculating two different arrays of data.
I pass two arrays of data in an adapter.
 like this.

```
List<LstJourneyOneWay> departList;
List<LstJourneyReturn> arriveList;
```

I bind the array also in `onBindViewHolder` method 
there i calculate data like

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewAdapter myViewAdapter, int position) {

LstJourneyOneWay lstJourneyOneWay = departList.get(position);
LstJourneyReturn lstJourneyReturn = arriveList.get(position);

ArrayList<LstItinerary> lstItinerary_depart = (ArrayList<LstItinerary>) lstJourneyOneWay.getLstItinerary();
ArrayList<LstItinerary> lstItinerary_arrive = (ArrayList<LstItinerary>) lstJourneyReturn.getLstItinerary();

Float custFare_depart = lstItinerary_depart.get(0).getCustomerFare();
Float custFare_arrive = lstItinerary_arrive.get(0).getCustomerFare();

Float totalFare = custFare_depart + custFare_arrive;
myViewAdapter.txt_TotalFare.setText("₹ " + totalFare)   }
```

now I want to sort data in recycler view according to the total fare. How can I do?
this is my sorting code.

```
// Sorting Prise
public void sortingData_Prise(Boolean isAscending) {
    if (isAscending) {
        Collections.sort(departList,  new Comparator<LstJourneyOneWay>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(LstJourneyOneWay asc_lstJour_one, LstJourneyOneWay asc_lstJour_two) {
                if (asc_lstJour_one.getLstItinerary().get(0).getCustomerFare() > asc_lstJour_two.getLstItinerary().get(0).getCustomerFare()) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        });

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.e("suraj", "sorting ascending");

    } else {

        Collections.sort(departList, new Comparator<LstJourneyOneWay>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(LstJourneyOneWay asc_lstJour_one, LstJourneyOneWay asc_lstJour_two) {
                if (asc_lstJour_one.getLstItinerary().get(0).getCustomerFare() < asc_lstJour_two.getLstItinerary().get(0).getCustomerFare()) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        });

        notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.e("suraj", "sorting descending");
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you sort the arraylists before adding it to recyclerview. this way a lot off overhead of notifyDataSetChanged() will be save. also why are you returning -1 always . what is the benefit of if and else there.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help here, but sadly I need much assumption since I don't know what your Model class represents.

If you're trying to compare 2 number values and sort according to them, you can easily return the result of subtracting the two numbers.

```
Collections.sort(departList, new Comparator<LstJourneyOneWay>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(LstJourneyOneWay asc_lstJour_one, LstJourneyOneWay asc_lstJour_two) {
                return asc_lstJour_one.getLstItinerary().get(0).getCustomerFare() - 
      asc_lstJour_two.getLstItinerary().get(0).getCustomerFare();
            }
        });
```

You can also make the method shorter by making a small adjustment to how you handle the ASC and DESC flag

```
int order = (isAscending ? 1 : 0) * -1;
```

Then:

```
Collections.sort(departList, new Comparator<LstJourneyOneWay>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(LstJourneyOneWay asc_lstJour_one, LstJourneyOneWay asc_lstJour_two) {
                return order * 
      asc_lstJour_one.getLstItinerary().get(0).getCustomerFare() -
      asc_lstJour_two.getLstItinerary().get(0).getCustomerFare();
            }
        });
```

Here, multiplying by `order` simply reverses the sorting if it is -1.

Comment: I want to show calculated data in the recycler view. One data I got from depart array and second data I got from arriving array. like this. 

'Float custFare_depart = lstItinerary_depart.get(0).getCustomerFare();
Float custFare_arrive = lstItinerary_arrive.get(0).getCustomerFare();

Float totalFare = custFare_depart + custFare_arrive;'

I added the total amount data successfully in recyclerView.
now i want to sort the total data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your model class so i am writing this code else this is not the good practice.

```
List<LstJourneyOneWay> departList;
List<LstJourneyReturn> arriveList;
List<BothList> bothList = new ArrayList<>;
```

wherever you got both array just call this function

```
void addBothList()
  {
   bothList.clear();
   for(int i=0;i<departList.size();i++)
   {
       bothList.add(new BothList(departList.get(0),arriveList.get(0)));
   }

  }
```

after this sort this list by calling this function

void sort()
   {

```
   Collections.sort(bothList, new Comparator<BothList>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(BothList o1, BothList o2) {
           ArrayList<LstItinerary> lstItinerary_depart = (ArrayList<LstItinerary>) o1.lstJourneyOneWay.getLstItinerary();
           ArrayList<LstItinerary> lstItinerary_arrive = (ArrayList<LstItinerary>) o1.lstJourneyReturn.getLstItinerary();

           Float custFare_depart = lstItinerary_depart.get(0).getCustomerFare();
           Float custFare_arrive = lstItinerary_arrive.get(0).getCustomerFare();

           Float totalFare = custFare_depart + custFare_arrive;


           lstItinerary_depart = (ArrayList<LstItinerary>) o2.lstJourneyOneWay.getLstItinerary();
           lstItinerary_arrive = (ArrayList<LstItinerary>) o2.lstJourneyReturn.getLstItinerary();

            custFare_depart = lstItinerary_depart.get(0).getCustomerFare();
            custFare_arrive = lstItinerary_arrive.get(0).getCustomerFare();
           Float totalFare1 = custFare_depart + custFare_arrive;
           return (int)(totalFare-totalFare1);
       }
   });
```

}

now use this list in your on onBindViewHolder function.

BothList class is as follows:-

```
class BothList
{
    LstJourneyOneWay lstJourneyOneWay;
    LstJourneyReturn lstJourneyReturn;
    BothList(LstJourneyOneWay lstJourneyOneWay,LstJourneyReturn 
          lstJourneyReturn) {
      this.lstJourneyOneWay=lstJourneyOneWay;
      this.lstJourneyReturn=lstJourneyReturn;
  }

}
```

Comment: Vaibhav Kumar , How can we add two model class in arraylist 
List<LstJourneyOneWay,LstJourneyReturn> bothList = new ArrayList<>;

it allows onlye one model class. that's the main issue 
List<LstJourneyOneWay> departList = new ArrayList<>;

Comment: have you see this List<LstJourneyOneWay,LstJourneyReturn>. it has two model class LstJourneyOneWay and LstJourneyReturn.

Comment: Vaibhav kumar yes i see and it's not allow two model class in one arraylist

Comment: my bad. please see updated answer. everything is same except  List<BothList>

Comment: vaibhav kumar, that's I'm asking how to add bothlist in a single list. that's a big question. I'm stuck there.

Comment: suraj, is above solution not work for you? we have a list bothlist and it accept type BothList(class). If you see the BothList class it has members LstJourneyOneWay and LstJourneyReturn.

Comment: vaibhav kumar, your right, you nearby my questions answered, I'm getting the response also. but now the issue is I'm 5 .api calling at one time and getting all 5.api data. I want to add this result in a single array. using your solution only one .api data display in recycler view. How to solve this issue. How to merge another data also in ArrayList?